# YouTube sound delayed through Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: windows-8, audio, bluetooth, youtube, headphones

I have a pair of Turtle Beach Bluetooth headphones. They work perfectly on my S3 and old iPod Touch. The only problem that I have with them is when I try to watch YouTube on my laptop, as the sound is severely delayed. Everything else on my laptop works with my headphones. It's fine when I plug the headphones in, but that obviously defeats the whole purpose of having wireless headphones. How can I reduce the audio lag on YouTube?

Comment: Have you checked if the Bluetooth speakers work correctly on another PC. ??
Are you facing this issue only when playing video via a specific program ??

Answer (score 0):

You can get an external adapter

If you happen to get one, get a good Bluetooth 4.1 one

There may be some problems with system config but they won't come in your way

Don't attempt to remove the Bluetooth from your laptop